# Setting toggle switch value

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How can I switch the toggle switch button to be true without triggering the `ToggleSwitch_Checked` function?

I am using the `toggleswitch.IsChecked` property, but this is triggering the previously mentioned function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the events to be triggered when first setting the value of the control you could simply not attach the event handler(s) until the initial values have been set.